# Remove service on docker-compose through overriding

Tags: docker-compose, devops, devops-services

I want to remove a container defined in docker-compose.yml file when we run in composition/override with another file docker-compose.prod.yml, by example:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: 2
services: 

  www:
    image: php56

  db_for_development:
    image: mariadb
```

override with:

```
# docker-compose.prod.yml
version: 2
services: 

  www:
    image: php70

  db_for_development:
    [control: override-and-remove] # hypothesis
```

Then, when running:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml ps
```

Actually, i have `www` and `db_for_development` together.

I want only `www` container, not others.

Answer (score 29):

You may have to switch to version: 3 to do this, I believe on version: 2 you can use the "scale" parameter but I'm not 100% sure.

Anyways, you can override the "replicas" parameter like this:

```
# docker-compose.prod.yml
version: "3"
services: 

  db_for_development:
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
```

Comment: `deploy` key used to be only for swarm. (See here, for example: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4672) Does Compose support it now? I could not find it in docs, but in my experiments, looks like it does... Still better to have some doc to refer.

Comment: You answered your own question . . . note that six year old issue is . . . closed. Follow it through and you can find the release where it became supported?

Answer (score 13):

You're going about this backwards

docker-compose.yml -> specify all services that will be always running

docker-compose.override.yml -> gets picked up automatically, usually used for development

docker-compose.*.yml -> special cases

So, in your case:

You don't remove a container defined in docker-compose.yml, you add it by override with another file or customize it with docker-compose.prod.yml, by example:

### docker-compose.yml -> this is the base

```
version: 2
services: 
  www:
    image: php56
```

### docker-compose.override.yml -> this is dev

```
version: 2
services: 
  db_for_development:
    image: mariadb
```

### docker-compose.production.yml -> this is prod

```
version: 2
services: 
  www:
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=production
    env_file:
      - /home/ubuntu/production-app
```

### docker-compose.admin.yml -> this is for the dba

```
version: 2
services: 
  adminer:
  image: adminer
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

## instructions:

For development, docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml will be used just by running

```
$ docker-compose up
```

Production, manually specify both files

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml up --remove-orphans
```

If you want to bring also bring adminer up (not recommended for production, but sometimes needed anyways)

```
$  docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.production.yml -f docker-compose.admin.yml up
```

Lastly, when you're done with adminer, just run the production command again this will leave adminer running as an orphan, and you do not want that. That's why the flag --remove-orphans is for

Comment: Thanks @Magus, this is a good practices tip but not is a response on my exact request! I'm not looking for the right way to do composition of prod/dev env. The idea is found the best way to remove container throug override

Comment: no problem. the dev/prod is a common scenario that I used to show how the overriding works, you can't remove services through overriding.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you want to remove (disable) a service that's defined in your compose file

Contents of `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  app:
    restart: always
    image: "rasa/rasa-x-demo:${RASA_X_DEMO_VERSION}"
    expose:
      - "5055"
    depends_on:
      - rasa-production
```

Contents of `docker-compose.override.yml`

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  app:
    image: alpine:latest
    command: "true"
    entrypoint: "true"
```

Done. Now your container will still launch but it's disabled using an empty image

Comment: That would still consume resources by booting up an alpine linux. Not the ideal solution.

Comment: Of course, it will. ~35MB RAM. Ideally, you wouldn't have null services in your compose file.

Comment: FYI the `rasa-production` depends_on would still be in play, which is probably not what anyone expects.

Comment: this will not disable the service, just make the service unusable.

Comment: Work for me. I'd add a `restart: "no"` in case it has the restart policy specified in one of the overridden yml files.

Comment: @Amir, if you don't want the size of an alpine image then [`tianon/true:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/r/tianon/true/tags) would save some bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is possible by using the [profile](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) feature added in docker compose version '3.9'

The idea is that in your `docker-compose.prod.yml`, set a dummy profile for the service to be removed, and call `docker compose up` without specifying that profile. So in your case:

```yaml
# docker-compose.prod.yml
version: '3.9' # make sure the version is at least 3.9
services: 
  db_for_development:
    profiles:
      - dummy-profile
```

Running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d` will not bring up the `db_for_development` at all.

More examples of how profile works can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/15-profiles/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Your only real option would be to specify the services (selectively) when running `docker-compose up`.